# JWKS URI needed in node

Tags: node.js, jwt

I'm setting up my authentication and authorization policy using jwt en jwks in a node-ts environment but I don't know where I can get my jwksuri from.

```
const authenticate = jwt({
  secret: jwksRsa.expressJwtSecret({
    // TODO: fill in
    jwksUri: '',
    cache: true,
    rateLimit: true,
    jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
  }),
  algorithms: ['RS256'],
});
```

I don't want to rely on the service of Auth0 or make an account or anything if possible.